# Passing parameter value to hiding element expression. BIRT

Tags: report, birt

I am trying to pass a parameter value to the hiding column element (in a table) in the expression box, so that if the value it's false it will not show the column.

Ex: my parameter is an int ( 2013 or 2014 or 2015..)

I tried the following but with no succes:

```
if(params["pStartEI"].value > 2014)
this.getStyle().display="none"; 
else
this.getStyle().display="block";
```

or the following:

```
if(params["pStartEI"].value > 2014)
{
true;
}
false;
```

Please tell me if you encountered this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
if(params["pStartEI"].value > 2014)
{
    true;
}
else
{
    false;
}
```